# Add entries to AllUserData from SQL

Tags: sql

I have been tasked with having our application make entries into our customer's Sharepoint database.

I have found the table where I think these entries are stored ("AllUserData"), but there are almost a dozen columns where I have no idea what they are for, and how they related to other tables, especially the columns that contain GUIDs.

These seems like a very hacky way have an application talk to sharepoint. Are there suposed to be some web services or API's that I should be using to do this?

UPDATE: ON their share point site, they have a listing of equipment. In our program they want us to add another piece of equipment. I am completely new to sharepoint, but from what I have found so far it seems that I have to first find the list these pieces of equipment go into and then add the item on the fly?

Comment: don't touch sharepoint database, you may end up in complete mess.

Comment: First of all you should try to explain what are you trying to achieve. As this now is a clear example of an XY Problem :)

Answer (score 5):

This is [completely unsupported](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/841057)! Do not read or write data to SharePoint databases. You need to go through the SharePoint Object Model, namely using [`SPWeb.EnsureUser`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.ensureuser.aspx) which will add the entry if it does not exist.

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V4uV3icrmw0

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways how to add items to SharePoint lists and the approach that you want to take is definitely not on the list.

1. Using C# (server object model) - code needs to be run on SP server.
2. Using C# (Client object model) - add items to SharePoint List using CSOM.
3. SharePoint PowerShell.
4. SharePoint Web Services (jQuery). Query Ajax function is used to POST the data to the Lists.asmx web service.
5. SharePoint REST API.

The last two options are the ones you would want to look into.

1. SharePoint Web Services - take a look at [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms440289.aspx) and [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.updatelistitems.aspx) article. It says "Update List Items" but refer to XML examples on the second link how to add New List Items.
2. SharePoint REST API. Take a look at [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn292552.aspx) and [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj164022.aspx).